# (PHP project) (Unit Test Success) (not displayed])

Tags: php, unit-testing

The "**Unit Test Success**" is **not displayed** for my PHP project after successful analysis.

I use : **SonarQube : 5.1** --
**PHP Plugin : 2.5** --
**PHPUnit : 4.7.6**

I first run PHPUnit (with --coverage-xml and --coverage-clover options) and then run sonar (with -Dsonar.php.coverage.reportPath and -Dsonar.php.tests.reportPath and also with -Dsonar.tests specifying tests source directory).

On SonarQube, the "Unit Tests Coverage" is displayed with "Line coverage" but unfortunately, without "Unit Test Success".

I’ve read many forums about this problem but the only way I found is to set “sonar.tests” variable that I’ve already done.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,

Wognin

Comment: report = target directory of project <br/>
# running PHPUnit
php phpunit.phar --log-junit ${report}/phpunitTest.xml --coverage-clover ${report}/clover.xml --coverage-xml ${report}
# running maven 
mvn -Dsonar.php.coverage.reportPath ${report}/clover.xml -Dsonar.php.tests.reportPath=${report}/phpunitTest.xml -Dsonar.tests=**/src/TestUnit/Controller/*  org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved.

The problem was, may be, about SonarQube server.

The Sonar Maven runner  was OK but on SonarQube server the project was not updated.
We have noticed that the filesystem of the temp directory of SonarQube server was about to be fully.

We have empty the temp directory and now the "Unit Test Success" is displyed for the PHP project and the history is also updated.

We are planning, right now to upgrade SonarQue from 5.1 to 5.1.2 (version that correct this problem).

Thanks,

WOGNIN